Apollo gateway error formatting with NestJS
I have GraphQL services (apollo) made with NestJS federated by apollo gateway.
My services return a formatted graphql error, I add an internal error code and some other information in the extensions. I return an ApolloError.
It worked very well when I requested the service directly, but since I used a gateway to federate, no. the gateway returns its own error, and I do not have access to the basic error in its error format.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Service setup:
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloFederationDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloFederationDriver,
  // autoSchemaFile: true,
  autoSchemaFile: {
    federation: 2,
  },
  playground: false,
  buildSchemaOptions: {
    orphanedTypes: [TeamDto],
  },
  formatError: (gqlError, error) => {
    const isBaseError = error?.['extensions']?.['is_error'];
    console.log('formatError', error);

    if (isBaseError) {
      return error['extensions'];
    }
    return new BaseError(gqlError.message, KnowError.GRAPHQL_ERROR, 500, {
      code: gqlError.extensions?.code,
    }).toJSON();
  },
})

Gateway setup:
GraphQLModule.forRoot<ApolloGatewayDriverConfig>({
  driver: ApolloGatewayDriver,
  server: {
    playground: false,
    plugins: [
      ApolloServerPluginLandingPageLocalDefault(),
    ],
    formatError: (gqlError, error: any) => {
      const serviceError =
        error.extensions.response?.body?.errors?.[0]?.extensions;

      console.log('formatError', error.extensions);

      return gqlError;
    },
  },
  gateway: {
    supergraphSdl: new IntrospectAndCompose({
      subgraphs: [
        { name: 'account', url: 'http://localhost:3001/graphql' },
        // { name: 'team', url: 'http://localhost:3002/graphql' },
      ],
    }),
  },
})

I tried via the extensions (plugins) I managed to access the error via: buildService.didReceiveResponse but I don't know how to return this error
